# I get disconnected from LAN every few minutes

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to play a LAN server with my sibling, but every few minutes, I lag then get disconnected.  It tells me that the connection was forcibly closed by a remote host.  We have the same wifi, and also I have let Java through firewall on both computers.  We run 1.10.2 and Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

**Try using your public IP adress instead of a local one**

I have the same problem that you describe with a computer in my local network. I tried every solution that came to mind like completely uninstall java then reinstall, update graphic card drivers, open ports through the firewall but NOTHING worked.

The solution I found and that seems working really fine is that instead of using your local ip address where the server is located (*example: 192.168.1.103*) for the server, use the public address (*example: 205.108.34.75*)

You can find your IP adress [here](https://www.whatismyip.com)